# How to set frame parameters for top and left in Emacs 24.3 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to position my my Emacs frame using `default-frame-alist` but I cannot get it to work. I would like the frame to fill the whole height of the screen, but not the whole width of the screen. It should be positioned on the left edge of the screen.

I am using Emacs version 24.3.1 on Ubuntu 14.04. I tried:

```
(tool-bar-mode -1)
(setq default-frame-alist
      `((auto-lower . nil)
    (auto-raise . nil)
    (foreground-color . "black")
    (background-color . "white")
    (cursor-color . "grey")
    (height . 45) 
    (width . 110)
    (user-position . t)
    (top . 0)
    (left . 0)))
(set-foreground-color  "black")
(set-background-color  "white")
(set-cursor-color  "grey")
```

This gives
[image]

As seen, the frame does not float completely to the left edge. There is also a small space below the frame (difficult to see on the screenshot).

Comment: I don't see any problems with your settings, except that `(set-foreground-color "black")` and `(set-background-color "white")` are not needed when incorporating those same settings into your `default-frame-alist`.  You can also incorporate `(cursor-color . "grey")` into your `default-frame-alist` and then eliminate `(set-cursor-color "grey")` if you want to make that the default for all frames.  You might also want to try placing your settings at the very beginning of your `.emacs` file and see if that helps any.  The developer snapshot of Emacs may also be of interest to you.

Comment: I have the same problem: window is placed with 10-20 pixels offset on BOTH top and left sides (see https://postimg.cc/87HMFHqK). Ubuntu 18.04, Emacs 24.5.1

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks OK to me wrt `top` and `left`. And yes, setting `default-frame-alist` *should* work from your init file.

I can't see much from your screen shot, but if you feel that the resulting `top` and `left` values are not what you set them to then consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

You can **check the actual frame parameters** easily (no need for a screenshot). Just do **`M-: (frame-parameters)`** in the questionable frame. If the `top` and `left` values do not correspond to what you defined for `default-frame-alist`: (1) first try to narrow things down (get rid of the rest of the code in your example), (2) then file a bug report if the problem is still there.

There might be a platform-specific bug, so be sure to use `report-emacs-bug` and include relevant info about your platform.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant parameter value for the height issue is `fullscreen`; add `(fullscreen . fullheight)` to your `default-frame-alist`; you can also use `fullboth` to have fullscreen for both vertical and horizontal dimensions.  (YMMV: I don't use Unity so don't know if this will cover the top panel or simply sit flush with it.)

Setting `(left . 0)` works for me, but again, YMMV as it may simply set the Emacs frame flush to Unity's toolbar rather than cover it up, which is probably a Unity issue rather than an Emacs issue.

Comment: Thanks. `(fullscreen . fullheight)` works for height. But setting `(left . 0)` does still not work. I get the same result as shown in my question above. For your information: `(fullscreen . maximized)` does not cover up the Unity launchbar, whereas `(fullscreen . fullboth)` covers everything.

Comment: Here's another thought, based on [this manual page](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Position-Parameters.html#Position-Parameters).  You can try setting the left parameter to a negative number, but apparently it requires some convoluted syntax to get there: `(set-frame-parameter nil 'left '(+ -25))` will set the left edge 25 pixels off the screen to the left (adjust as useful).

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot get this to work. Even `(set-frame-parameter nil 'left '(+ 100))` does not affect the position at all. I am calling this function in my `~/.emacs` below the call to `default-frame-alist`. I also tried to insert it into the argument list of `default-frame-alist` using `(left . '(+ 100))` but nothing happend with the horizontal position..

Comment: Odd that it's not responding (and also odd that it's not flushleft to begin with).  Try `(set-frame-position (selected-frame) 0 0)` and, if it doesn't work, I'm out of ideas.  It may require someone with more Unity knowledge than mine (which is minimal; I ditched it to avoid the visual noise).

Comment: Ok it seems that `set-frame-parameter` and `set-frame-position` cannot be called from `~/.emacs`. They does not have any effect at all. But I tried `(set-frame-position (selected-frame) 100 0)` from scratch buffer afterwards, and it worked. But still `(set-frame-position (selected-frame) 0 0)` does not change anything from my question above..